# Dialogflow python client versioning

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am using [python client](https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2) for accessing dialogflow's functionality.
My question is: does

```
import dialogflow
```

and

```
import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
```

have any difference?
As per my experience, all the methods are the same. In the samples given by Google, `import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow` has been used and I could not see any difference between the two.

Please note that here I am talking about version v2 in python client, and not the dialogflow API version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out where a module is located by looking at its `__file__` attribute. Doing this for `dialogflow` and then looking at the file you will see that it does indeed import from `dialogflow_v2`, i.e. is just a shortcut for the `dialogflow_v2` import:

```
# <project>/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dialogflow/__init__.py

from __future__ import absolute_import

from dialogflow_v2 import AgentsClient
from dialogflow_v2 import ContextsClient
from dialogflow_v2 import EntityTypesClient
from dialogflow_v2 import IntentsClient
from dialogflow_v2 import SessionEntityTypesClient
from dialogflow_v2 import SessionsClient
from dialogflow_v2 import enums
from dialogflow_v2 import types

__all__ = (
    'enums',
    'types',
    'AgentsClient',
    'ContextsClient',
    'EntityTypesClient',
    'IntentsClient',
    'SessionEntityTypesClient',
    'SessionsClient',
)
```

The same is not true for `dialogflow_v2beta1` however, to get the newest features you would have to import that directly.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @gmolau is sufficient enough, still I am posting another answer because I have contacted Dialogflow support team and wanted to quote their statement.

Here is the response from Dialogflow team:

> dialogflow and dialogflow_v2 are the same while dialogflow_v2beta1 is
>   a different module since it contains beta features not generally
>   available on dialogflow_v2